# Pausing the execution of a binary file using C?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

I have a binary file that I can execute in C by using the system() command or popen(). when running the binary in the linux filesystem I can use ctrl + z to pause the execution of the program and the fg to resume the execution. Is there any possible way in which I could do this in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a SIGSTOP signal to it. See the signals manpage on how to do it. You can continue the process by sending it a SIGCONT signal. You'll need the process ID for this, so you'll have to use fork+exec instead of plain system.